# Java: Could not find or load main class ubuntu

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, server, javac

Here is my file layout 
`MUD-master/MUD/src/mud/MUDServer.java`
Note that mud contains all my java classes, but the other ones aren't relevant to this question.
Essentially I'm trying to to initilise this MUDServer on a port.
I wrote a bash script that, in theory, should work but I'm having some issues. This is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is a test"
cd "MUD/src/mud"
echo "cd 'MUD/src/mud'"
#javac -cp /MUD/scr/mud/*.java
echo "javac *.java"
javac *.java

gnome-terminal -- rmiregistry 50010
gnome-terminal -- java mud.MUDServer 50010 50011
gnome-terminal -- java mud.clientMain localhost 50010 50012
gnome-terminal -- java mud.clientMain localhost 50010 50013
gnome-terminal -- java mud.clientMain localhost 50010 50014
```

The program working up to the `rmiregistry 50010` line, and then stops.
I try to manually initilise the server, but using the command 
`java mud.MUDServer 50010 50011`, but I get this error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class mud.MUDServer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mud.MUDServer
```

After some research I tried this:

```
java -cp mud.MUDServer 50010 50011
```

which got me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 50010
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 50010
```

This is a snippet the MUDServer.java:

```
package mud;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

/**
 *
 * This is the main class for initialisation of the MUD Server
 * It deals with the start up of the server, and also
 * covers any security issues that may arise from connecting 
 *
 */

public class MUDServer {

    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        if(args.length < 2)
        {
            System.err.println("Usage:\n Java MUDServer <registryport> <serverport>");
            return;
        }
        try 
        {
            String host = (InetAddress.getLocalHost()).getCanonicalHostName();
            int regPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

            // Security
            System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "mud.policy");
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());

            // Generate remote objects
            ServerImplementation mudServer = new ServerImplementation();
            ServerInterface mudInter = (ServerInterface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(mudServer, serverPort);

            String regURL = "rmi://" + host + ":" + regPort + "/MUDServer";
            System.out.println("Registering" + regURL);
            Naming.rebind(regURL, mudInter);
        }
        catch(java.net.UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }


    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've spend a while trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: ```/home/platypus/Desktop/MUD-master/mud```

Comment: I would be hesitant to use the absolute path because I need it to work on different machines also, but the ```cd ..``` worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Abra I am newish to java, this is my first time having to write something this complicated using java. I have more experience in other programming language. Virgin.